# Azure VM session timeout in RDP

Tags: azure, cloud, rdp

I am evaluating Azure VM with MSDN subscription. I created a few server 2012 VMs. However, apparently Azure timeout the connections idle after a few minutes.

How to extend the timeout period at the Azure side?

Comment: What sort of connections are you talking about?

Comment: I am using Remote Desktop Connection. Since I would navigate between VMs, I would like them to stay connected for at least half hour each when idle.

Answer (score 0):

This might be bit late ,  i update the response anyways . ITs possible to increate the time out by updating Keep Alive setting in the registry. This setting causes to send “heartbeat” packets to connected clients every so often.  With this setting the connection can be prolonged.

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal
>   Services] "KeepAliveEnable"=dword:00000001
>   "KeepAliveInterval"=dword:00000001